# Describing several lines in graph

Tags: word-choice

So I have a graph that depicts 3 lines. Each line represents a different level of consumption `c`. I am having trouble choosing the correct word to indicate the difference between the lines. My first attempt was the following.

```
Figure 1 shows the result for different levels of consumption c.
```

But I am not very happy with the word `different`, because it sounds to me a bit like `different from a baseline`. But what I want to say is they are merely different among themselves.

My second attempt is this.

```
Figure 1 shows the result for varying levels of consumption c.
```

Is there a clearer word than `different` or `varying`? If not which one do you prefer.

Thanks for reading.

[image: Figure 1]

Edit: `s` -> `c`

Comment: I think you can keep "different" and change "levels": Figure 1 shows the result [in something] for different values of consumption.

Comment: The "[space] **s**" at the end of each sentence looks odd, as though you can't decide if a plural is needed. The diagram uses **c**.

Comment: Thanks for point this out. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that "different **rates** of consumption" would be more idiomatic than "levels", as "consumption" is the action of using up a resource *over time*.

For an alternative to "different", I personally would not use "varying", because that can also mean *fluctuating*, whereas it seems you are trying to refer to three *constant* rates.

You could use the words "distinct" or "differing", but my preference would be "contrasting", as this shows that you have chosen the three rates of consumption for *contrast*.

> Figure 1 shows the results for three contrasting rates of consumption.

Comment: Just beat me to posting "**various rates** of consumption."